# Tweepy Update with media error

Tags: python, api, twitter, status, tweepy

I want to post an Image to twitter every hour out of an folder.

```
import os, tweepy, time, sys,
path="C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\dunny"
files=os.listdir(path)

CONSUMER_KEY = 'hide'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'hide'
ACCESS_KEY = 'hide'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'hide'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for i in path:
    api.update_with_media(files)
    time.sleep(3600)
```

This is the error msg which I get if I try to run the code.

```
C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop>python htmlparse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlparse.py", line 14, in <module>
    api.update_with_media(files)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 98, in update_with_me
dia
    headers, post_data = API._pack_image(filename, 3072, form_field='media[]', f
=f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 713, in _pack_image
    if os.path.getsize(filename) > (max_size * 1024):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `path` string a raw string literal:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\dunny"
```

or use double backward slashes:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Desktop\\dunny"
```

or use forward slashes:

```
path = "C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/dunny"
```

`\U` (from `"C:\Users..."`) is an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) used to define a 32-bit hex value. This is why you're getting the Unicode error.

---

The other issue is with your `for` loop at the bottom. Try this instead (you'll need to `import os` at the top):

```
for i in files:
    filename = os.path.join(path, i)
    api.update_with_media(filename)
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Previously, when you were using `for i in path:`, you were iterating over each character in the string `path`. Then, in the body of the loop, `api.update_with_media(files)` was trying to send the entire list of file names, when the function only accepts one.

Comment: Still dont work TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: @user3834405 see my update - the logic in your `for` loop was incorrect.

Comment: Now i get tweepy.error.TweepError: Unable to access file

Comment: @user3834405 OK, one more update. Put `import os` at the top of your file, then alter your `for` loop as in my answer. Basically, you're constructing the full path to the file you want to pass to `update_with_media()`.